# Try expression of Unit does not conform to expected type

Tags: java, scala

I have a scenario where I need to call a Java API from a Scala code which returns `void` and throws an exception in case lets say if the argument is not valid. I am currently handling it as follows, however I was wondering if there is a way to avoid `var` and if there is an idiomatic way to achieve this in Scala:

```
object TestTry extends App {

  def createSampleRequest(message: String): Option[SampleRequest] = {
    val sampleRequest = new SampleRequest()

    //I really want to avoid var
    var parsedSampleRequest = Option(SampleRequest)

    //Calling a Java method returns void
    try sampleRequest.fromString(fix, null, true) 
    catch {
      case e: InvalidMessage => parsedSampleRequest = Option.empty
    }

    parsedSampleRequest
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use [`Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/util/Try.html):

```
import scala.util.Try

def createSampleRequest(message: String): Option[SampleRequest] = {
  val sampleRequest = new SampleRequest()      
  Try(sampleRequest.fromString(fix, null, true))
    .map(s => Option(sampleRequest))
    .getOrElse(None)
}
```

If the call to `fromString` throws an exception, `result` will be `None`; if the call does not throw an exception, `result` will be a `Some[SampleRequest]` that contains the `sampleResult` instance.

As @OlegPyzhcov points out in a comment, a more concise version of this is:

```
Try { sampleRequest.fromString(fix, null, true); sampleRequest } .toOption
```

Comment: `Try` has `toOption`, so you can replace your `map ... getOrElse` with that

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov: That won't work because `sampleRequest.fromString(...)` returns a `Unit`, and we want the final return type to be `Option[SampleRequest]`.

Comment: whoops, right, missed that bit. You can do multiple statements on creation however, e.g. `Try { sampleRequest.fromString(...); sampleRequest }.toOption`

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate variables altogether and return where needed :

```
object TestTry extends App {

  def createSampleRequest(message: String): Option[SampleRequest] = {
    val sampleRequest = new SampleRequest()

    try 
      sampleRequest.fromString(fix, null, true)
      Some(sampleRequest)
    catch
      case e: InvalidMessage => None
  }
}
```